# When i try putting a texture it give me this error: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level(python)

Tags: python

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController

grass_texture = load_texture('textures/grass_block.png')
brick_texture = load_texture('textures/brick_block.png')
stone_texture = load_texture('textures/stone_block.png')
dirt_texture = load_texture('textures/dirt_block.png')

class Voxel(Button):
    def __init__(self, position = (0,0,0)):
        super().__init__(
            parent = scene,
            position = position,
            model = 'textures/grass_block',
            origin_y = (0.5),
            texture = 'white_cube',
            color = color.color(0,0,random.uniform(0.9,1)),
            highlight_color = color.lime)

    def input(self,key):
        if self.hovered:
            if key == 'right mouse down':
                voxel = Voxel(position = self.position + mouse.normal)

            if key == 'left mouse down':
                destroy(self)

app = Ursina()

for z in range(40):
    for x in range(40):
        voxel = Voxel(position = (x,0,z))


player = FirstPersonController()

app.run()
```

When I type in these or maybe just one of them, it just gives me an indentation error. I've checked so many times but everything is literally in tabs. No matter where I put the texture variables, the error follows it. I am coding minecraft  in python- all I really have right now is a blank white platform that I can place blocks on. If it works fine please tell me how you set it up in sublime text 3. I'm pretty new to this.

[image]

Comment: Your code doesn't have any indentation. Make sure the code you post demonstrates the issue!

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. That's quite a large project you've chosen to undertake! I wish you luck. When posting questions about errors, it is good practice to past the exact error you get. In this case, it would be very helpful for us to see the exact line the indent error is pointing to.

Comment: I don't see any indentation problems in the posted snippet. Can you please provide us with the error traceback?

Comment: ```
grass_texture = load_texture('textures/grass_block.png')
brick_texture = load_texture('textures/brick_block.png')
stone_texture = load_texture('textures/stone_block.png')
dirt_texture = load_texture('textures/dirt_block.png')
```
are the lines that get the indent error, the problem i have is that 1, the textures dont load, and 2, the indent line keeps popping up in these lines. i can put in a picture too if u want

Comment: That error message looks like you manually screwed with your installed copy of the `psd_tools` module. Never manually edit installed modules. Your best option at this point is probably to uninstall and reinstall `psd_tools`.

Comment: i tried that, and now it gave me an OS error i-

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, these identation error comes when you mix the process of giving identation in your code.

What I meant to say is identation can be given using both `Tab` key or by pressing 4 times `space bar` key.

When you mix both these procedures in a single script, you may get this error. I would recommend you to use either `Tab` or 4 times `space bar` but not both in the same code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather common issue that I face from time to time.

Try hightlighting all your code and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> multiple times till all indentation is removed. Then highlight specific portions and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to fix all the indentation back to its original state.

Basically, remove and re-add all indentation using this method. That will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows that you've corrupted your copy of the `psd_tools` module, most likely by manually editing its files. Never manually edit installed modules like that.

Your best option at this point is probably to uninstall and reinstall `psd_tools`.